# Can I use the default console in a Win32 GUI application, or should I create a new one?

Tags: c++, winapi, console

I'm new to the Windows API and am programming in C++. I would like to have a console to output information to and receive keyboard commands via GetMessage. However, I can't just create a console application because if I do, it's impossible to read keyboard messages sent to that console with `GetMessage`. *Reacting to keyboard input via GetMessage is a requirement for this project.*

When I create  Win32 GUI application in Code::Blocks 13.12 (using MinGW to compile) and call `AllocConsole` at the beginning, I get error 5: "Access is denied". If I instead first use `FreeConsole`, `FreeConsole` succeeds without error; if I then use `AllocConsole`, a console window appears. The MSDN description of `FreeConsole` is:

> Detaches the calling process from its console.

This indicates that before I call FreeConsole, a console already existed (even though I couldn't see it and didn't explicitly create it). Is it an invisible console, or is it the one that always appears when running a Code::Blocks project? Is it pointless for me to use `FreeConsole` and then `AllocConsole`? Is there instead a way to make the console that already exists visible (if it's invisible) and able to receive keyboard input via `GetMessage`?

Here's an example of the stripped-down code that exhibits this behavior:

```
#include <windows.h>

DWORD dw = 0;

int WINAPI WinMain (HINSTANCE hThisInstance,
                    HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
                    LPSTR lpszArgument,
                    int nCmdShow)
{
    if (FreeConsole() == 0) {
        dw = GetLastError();
        return dw;
    }

    if (AllocConsole() == 0) {
        dw = GetLastError();
        return dw;
    }
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: Why do you want to use GetMessage? Anyway, you *can* use it in console application.

Comment: @dsi The reason I need to use GetMessage is complicated, but you can read more about my situation [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21139698/how-can-i-recognize-keyboard-input-in-c-with-windows-api-using-getmessage-in) if you really want to know.

Comment: @dsi I know I can use GetMessage, but I don't think I can use it *to get input from the keyboard*. At the question linked to in my previous comment, I asked "Does anyone have any tips for how to direct keyboard input to the messaging system in my console application?" To which Hans Passant replied, "That's not possible. The console window is managed by a completely different executable, you can't mess with it."

Comment: @Cerran ok, have a look at MsgWaitForMultipleObjects function. It might be what you're looking for.

Comment: I cannot reproduce. I build a GUI app with mingw and my call to `AllocConsole` succeeds.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Well, that's interesting! I'm also using MinGW. Just to be sure, `AllocConsole` succeeds without first calling `FreeConsole`?

Comment: Dsi is correct that you can call `GetMessage` from a console application. However, you cannot use it to get *console keyboard input*, which seems to be what you want. Instead, I think you should put your USB-message-handling code into a separate thread, and then keep ordinary console I/O. Another option is to use Windows-specific console-input functions like `ReadConsoleInput`, and then use `MsgWaitForMultipleObjects` to wait on the console handle. It will tell you when you receive console input or a message, so you can know whether to call `GetMessage` or `ReadConsoleInput` next.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When I create Win32 GUI application in Code::Blocks (using MinGW to compile) and call `AllocConsole` at the beginning, I get error 5: *Access is denied*.

The explanation for your call to `AllocConsole` failing is that you are actually building a **console** application. Even though you use `WinMain`, mingw will still produce, by default, an executable that targets the console subsystem. You can use a tool like `dumpbin` to inspect the PE header to confirm my conclusion.

Compile with `-mwindows` to make sure that the executable targets the GUI subsystem.

Comment: That appears to be correct. Thanks for the help! When I specify `-mwindows` as a linker option, `AllocConsole` succeeds without first using `FreeConsole`, and the new console appears. It seems strange to me that this wouldn't automatically be specified in my project, considering I explicitly created it as a "Win32 GUI project" rather than a "Console application" in Code::Blocks. I still don't know why the console was invisible, but with `-mwindows`, I don't have to worry about that because the only console created is the one I explicitly create, which is visible by default.

Comment: I tried using dumpbin on my executable, but because I'm unfamiliar with the tool, I wasn't sure how to find the relevant information. But I guess the difference that `-mwindows` makes basically already proved your point. Thanks again, that was very helpful.

Comment: `dumpbin /headers myexe.exe | more` is what you need, and the value of interest is the subsystem. Either Windows CUI or Windows GUI.

Comment: Ah yes, I forgot about `more`. Indeed, without `-mwindows`, I get `3 subsystem (Windows CUI)`; with `-mwindows`, I get `2 subsystem (Windows GUI)`.